# plotting spectrogram of two or more audio file at a time

Tags: python

I have been working on heart sound signal in Matlab. Now I want to switch to Python but the problem with me is how to process two or more audio signals at a time. Thanks In advance

Comment: What do you mean "process two or more audio signals"?

Comment: I have a dataset of normal and abnormal heart sounds which contains a large number of audio signals. Now i want to plot spectrogram of the normal and abnormal heart sounds. So how to process the audio signals collectively???. I cannot select multiple audio signal???

Comment: Could you post the matlab code so I can understand what you mean?

Comment: Actually i want to plot spectrogram for whole normal dataset which contain a large number of audio signals.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea about selecting multiple audio files to process collectively.

Comment: This can be done in `python` using `scipy.spectrogram`... here is an [example](https://pythontic.com/visualization/signals/spectrogram).

Comment: plotting spectrogram for a signal audio signal is easy. I want to plot spectrogram of multiple signals collectively at a same time.

Comment: I see, so as I understand, you want to plot multiple spectrograms in one image like [these](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSikA3G5XG2W1-O0ngIKjzOP9Ss2PuPcscWPsTifRLGUQtE2R9e) for example.